# How to download Google Code via Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, google-code

I am new to Android and I want to downaload source code from this site:

- http://code.google.com/p/apv/source/

of an Android PDF viewer. I know how to download source from SVN but I have no idea what `hg clone` is. Can any one tell me how can I download this open source project?

Comment: https://www.mercurial-scm.org

Comment: what software i need to download from here? and how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Download](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download) and install Mercurial.

You will have a command line client: `hg`. Now you can get any sourcecode via `hg clone`:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/apv/
```

For a faster introduction to Mercurial, see http://hginit.com/.