# How to download a project from Code Google site in zip

Tags: google-code

I want to download https://code.google.com/p/futonic-lockscreenswitchwidget/ this project in a zip file. But I don't know how to do this.

In the Downloads tab, there is no any link for downloading the source code. I only have a link of apk file, but I want the source code.

I have `Download SVN` software also. but I don't know how to use this. I tried a lot but failed. Here is the screen shot of the `Download SVN`.

[image]

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900786/how-to-download-checkout-a-project-from-google-code-in-windows

Comment: Note also that this project uses Mercurial, not Subversion. The [Google Code page itself](https://code.google.com/p/futonic-lockscreenswitchwidget/source/checkout) links to some helpful resources.

Comment: how can i know this.? that this project uses Mercurial and not the Subversion and vice versa

Comment: This project using "MERCURIAL", here's a similar response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543089/how-to-download-google-code-via-mercurial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the source code

1. install [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads)
2. Add path to Environment variables
3. Open command prompt
4. Go to the required directory
5. Type the following command

> hg clone https://code.google.com/p/futonic-lockscreenswitchwidget/

Comment: I installed mercurial, how to 2nd step?

Comment: Thanks. I hv done it :) up voted

Comment: maybe this online tool help others : http://svndownload.eu5.org/